# Toolbar Android L Custom TextView Font not applying

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, toolbar

I have a problem with the new Toolbar in android.

I have a similar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tlb_wineoox_login"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <al.eng.utils.TextOratorStdMedium
        android:id="@+id/txt_home_acitivity_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#3f3434"
        android:textSize="@dimen/tetembedhjet_sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And the class of the custom TextView is like this:

```
public class TextOratorStdMedium extends TextView {

    public TextOratorStdMedium(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public TextOratorStdMedium(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public TextOratorStdMedium(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(final Context context) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Orator-Std-Medium.ttf");
                setTypeface(tf);

    }
}
```

In this way my code doesn't seem to change the font type. But if i make the custom text view with an thread that wait's for one second before changing the typeface than it works:

```
public class TextOratorStdMedium extends TextView {

    public TextOratorStdMedium(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public TextOratorStdMedium(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public TextOratorStdMedium(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(final Context context) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Orator-Std-Medium.ttf");
                setTypeface(tf);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

So it looks like the toolbar is somehow rewriting the type face of the custom textview after the creation. There is no style applied at all. How can this be possible? Do we have any other solution beside creating a new thread and waiting for some moments?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried reproduce your issue and every thing works fine... I think that the problem can be in different place

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak my ActionBarActivity implements an ViewPager with PagerSlidingTabStrip. Do you think this can have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it looks weird. Maybe you can try some of View lifecycle methods. Try override onMeasure(), onSizeChanged() or onAttachedToWindow(), but be aware of recursive calls.

Comment: I tried to but it doesn't seems to change the problem. Im having the problem with my nexus 5.

Comment: Only thing that comes into my mind is that you have custom theme/style, that overrides action bar style (or app theme). Does it work, if outside toolbar? Did you try new constructor for lollipop? (this one with 4 params)